# USB flash drive letter using python

Tags: python, windows

how to get drive letter and name of the USB connected to the system using python in windows

Answer (score 4):

It will give you list of all in use drives letters.

```
import win32api

drives = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
drives = drives.split('\000')[:-1]
print drives
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this to list all drives in windows:

```
>>> import os.path
>>> dl = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
>>> drives = ['%s:' % d for d in dl if os.path.exists('%s:' % d)]
>>> drives
```